# Core Data Relationships - Two entities to one entitiy

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship, relationship

I have three entities.

- Author
- Newspaper
- Dissertation

`Newspaper` and `Dissertation` both can have one or more `Author`.  I have managed to do this fine with `Newspaper`.  What I am trying to accomplish is to create the same link from `Dissertation` as that of `Newspaper`.  That means, I want authors (`Dissertation`) to link to parentEntity (`Author`).

Heres an image that may help.

[image: relationship]

As you can see, `Dissertation` currently links to newRelationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an abstract parent class named "Paper" or something, which has the "authors"-relationship to "Author". Let both "Newspaper" and "Dissertation" be subentities of "Paper".

If you do that, both subentities will have (=inherit) the relation (of their parent "Paper") to "Author", named "authors".